# Correlation calculation in Tableau and R

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have huge a dataset and have to calculate the correlation matrix for different indices based on the user's selection (Filter). I applied formula in both Tableau calculation field and R.

Both are successful if the indices have the required data and the output results are also the same. In case if any of the indices that I choose have less data than I required (i.e., Only 2 years data available, whereas i want to see for 3 years correlation).

"R" automatically ignores those indices which doesn't have the value for the time frame. Whereas in Tableau, it still calculates for the indices & shows result in output, even if it has one data point. Actually those indices shouldn't show any result like "R".

How to remove those Indices from Tableau calculation, any help on this regard would certainly appreciable.

**Note:** *It is very easy for me to use "R" instead of Tableau, however our Tableau server doesn't connect with "R Serve" due to technology restriction. Hence I recommended to use Tableau Calculations only*

**Tableau Calculation Code:**

```
(WINDOW_SUM(SIZE()*[ValueAcross]*[ValueDown])-WINDOW_SUM([ValueDown])*WINDOW_SUM‌​([ValueAcross])) / (SQRT(((WINDOW_SUM(SIZE()*[ValueAcross]^2)-WINDOW_SUM([ValueAcross])^2))*(WINDOW‌​_SUM(SIZE()*[ValueDown]^2)-WINDOW_SUM([ValueDown])^2)))
```

**R Calculation Code:**

```
Script_Real("cor(.arg1,.arg2, method='pearson')",([ValueAcross]),([ValueDown]))
```

Comment: Please provide codes used for Tableau and R, for comparison.

Comment: Click on Edit button above and edit your post, avoid putting code into comments.